# Text won't show inside <ul>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show captions under the thumbnail slider which are in lists. But the text won't show up unless I change the `<ul>` to `<div>`. You can find the thumbnail [here](https://www.realtyscale.com/crescent-bay-parel/#floor-plans). It is the first thumbnail. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: To ask a question you need to provide the actual code. Links to arbitrary sites are _not_ a replacement for that. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

give `font-size: 16px` to your `<p>`

if you will see in developer tools , calculated font size for `<p>` is actually `0px` thats why your text is not visible